# Importing only Updated Records From SQL to Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop

As We have a Table with 2 columns lets suppose in SQL
( we doesnt have any created_date,Updated_date,Flag  columns in SQL Source Table and not to modify source Table )

```
 id is primary key
  id name
  1 AAAAA
  2 BBBBB
  3 CCCCC
  4 ADAEAB
  5 GGAGAG
```

i pull the data using sqoop into hive as a Main table its ok
But if the source data is Updated like below

```
  id name
  1 ACACA
  2 BASBA
  3 CCHAH
  4 AASDA1
  5 GGAGAG
```

### Problem :

```
My Issue is that without effecting the Main table data in hive i need to pull the
Updated or Inserted or Deleted data using Sqoop and
also simultaneously update in the Hive Main Table without effecting the 
Existing once....
i have tried  tried to use
--incremental .... so on properties but no result....
```

### Result Should be:

```
output main table is having all the 10 records... it should be 5 records....
If we have More Records like millions of Records Then What is the Solution.....
```

### Requirement:

```
on day1 i have 1millions of records
on day 2 i have 1million + current day + updated lets say 2 million
on day2 i have to pull only updated and newly inserted data rather than whole data.
and also 
can Anyone Help me how to combine day1 hive data with day2 updated data...


In case if Anyone has Any other solution like any Alternative please suggest me 
Clearly Because i m new to hadoop....
```

Comment: If you don't have a column indicating "last updated" (or similar) for a given row, you're going to have to pull all the rows.  Some RDBMSs may store this as meta information, what vendor/version are you using?  If you don't want to update all rows in the destination db, then you have to put them in a temp table (on the destination db) to run a comparison against (examples on this site).  So your options are add a column (potentially), or run a full compare.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an internal table (base_table) for the first time load
2. Create an external table (incremental_table) for the incremental & updated records
3. Join the base_table & incremental_table based on primary key and max_date and create a view on top of it.
4. Create a temporary table(reporting table) on top of the view.
5. Drop the base_table and insert the data from reporting_table.
   Please refer to the below link :
   https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_dataintegration/content/incrementally-updating-hive-table-with-sqoop-and-ext-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't give you a option to update specific entries, but then there are some workarounds if you for specific cases,

for pulling only updated/fresh data you have to have a some sort of timestamp or a mechanism to derive what all rows were updated/added to you data after the last import.  once you have it you can either use --incremental with sqoop as a param or pass on a -- where clause in the query to pick only updated/inserted entries.

your second requirement is something which hive doesnt support that is to update the already loaded entries, so here's my 2 cents if it helps you.

load the new data in a different table or date partition and then do a left outer join b/w your existing hive table and this new table on your primary key to populate the updated columns in the existing table and **insert overwrite** this data in existing table.  though its not a one step process but this would work.